# Sci-fi/Fantasy book about humanoid plant people

Tags: story-identification

Can you help me identify this fantasy book that is based in a world where the people are plants? I think the book is written by two authors and there was some kind of plot twist at the end where the two main characters have sex and by doing so, some kind of important information is released and they save the world.

Comment: Book? This reminds me of a short story, though I can't remember the author. William Tenn, maybe? Or if sex is an important plot element, Philip José Farmer? Do you remember anything else about the book, for example what happens to these people? Do the plants move? When did you read the book and was it new then?

Comment: I'm reminded of a short story by two authors where the plot twist at the end is that the people turn out to be trees. But if I say which short story it is, I'll give away the surprise. Anyway, it doesn't have enough sex and I think it's too recent.

Answer (score 4):

Piers Anthony and Jo Anne Taeusch *The Secret of Spring*.

Spring is a sorcerer's daughter. The sorcerer locks some information within his daughter. The sorcerer dies, and an ambitious wizard "will do anything to get [Spring's secrets]... including the obvious". - from the back cover. Herb Moss is a sentient plant who romances Spring.

Comment: No upvotes? It's likely the correct answer, but the asker seems not available.

Comment: That's it, thank you very much.